# extract double values with XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue from yaml file

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, xmlrpc, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to extract some lists with double values.

Because it is a nested array,  it is not readable with NodeHandle getParam?

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue box;
nh.getParam("test/values", box);

if(box.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::Type::TypeArray && box.size() > 0 )){
    if(box[0].getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::Type::TypeArray && box[0].size() > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < box[0].size(); i++) {
                  ROS_INFO("value %f ",box[0][i]);
        }
    }}
```

yaml file:

```
test: 
  values: 
  - [  0.0,  0.1,  0.2]
  - [  0.0,   -0.1,  -0.2]
```

At this point, how can I get the double value?

Error message:

```
warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 8 has type ‘XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue’ [-Wformat=]
```

box[0][i].getDoubleFormat() returned %.16g, so it should be correct.

But an assert failed with

```
ROS_ASSERT(box[0][i].getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeDouble);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349890/extract-double-values-with-xmlrpc::xmlrpcvalue-from-yaml-file/) by [zFnq9](https://answers.ros.org/users/53736/zfnq9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first thing that you need is to change the way you wrote the YAML file.

```
 test: 
  values0: [  0.0,  0.1,  0.2]
  values1: [  0.0,   -0.1,  -0.2]
```

To something like that, each array has a name.

```
1| ros::NodeHandle node;
 |
2| std::vector<double> vectorVar;
3| node.getParam("test/values0", vectorVar);
```

And for each array, you must repeat step 2 and 3, or create a vector of a vector.

Let me aware if it is working, I tried this solution here before, but we never know.

---

Originally posted by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) with karma: 378 on 2020-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zFnq9](https://answers.ros.org/users/53736/zfnq9/) on 2020-04-20**:
Thanks! With this method, do I need each name for getParam ("values**0**", "values**1**, ...") ?
It should handle different length.

**Comment by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) on 2020-04-20**:
Yes. however, the syntax isn't exactly this one.
Should be this one: `node.getParam(PARAM_NAME, VARIABLE)`

So if you have more than one array in the YAML file. You should do something like this:

```
node.getParam("test/value0", value0Vector);
node.getParam("test/value1", value1Vector);
node.getParam("test/value2", value2Vector);
```

But you always can use loop statements to make this smart.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> vectorVar
for(int index = 0; ros::param::has("test/values" + std::to_string(index)); index++) {
    std::vector<double> tempVector;
    node.getParam("test/values" + std::to_string(index), tempVector);    
    vectorVar.push_back(tempVector);
}
```

Instead of using a tempVector you could resize your vector ( if the number of elements is known) and use `vectorVar.at(index)`

And there aren't problems arrays have a different number of elements.